# Creating Active Directory user with password in C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm looking for a way to create Active Directory users and set their password, preferably without giving my application/service Domain Admin privileges.

I've tried the following:

```
DirectoryEntry newUser = _directoryEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + fullname, USER);
newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = username;
newUser.Properties["userPassword"].Value = password;
newUser.Properties["mail"].Value = email;
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

The user is created, but it seems the password is never set on the user.

Does anyone have an idea on how to set the user's password initially when creating the user? I know about

```
.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password })
```

But that requires my code to be run with Domain Admin privileges. As I don't really see the point to grant my code Domain Admin privileges, just to set the initial password (I also allow user password resets, but those run in the context of that particular user), I am hoping someone has a clever solution that doesn't require me to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's the only option we had, I bet you're in the same boat, but provided you the 3.5 alternative below in case it's an option.  I have 1/4 the code vs the `DirectoryEntry` style that was the only option before, I **highly** recommend giving the new namespace a look.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do this whole process much easier now with System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (long as you're on .Net 3.5):

[See here for a full rundown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384369.aspx)

Here's a quick example of your specific case:

```
using(var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
  using(var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
  {
    up.SamAccountName = username;
    up.EmailAddress = email;
    up.SetPassword(password);
    up.Enabled = true;
    up.ExpirePasswordNow();
    up.Save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the context and principle objects when you're done.  This is best done with `using` statements on `pc` and `up`.

Comment: @tvanfosson - Great point, even quick examples should be copy/paste worthy, updated!

Answer (score 5):

Yes can also use below code to create bulk of users

```
DirectoryEntry ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=TestOU,DC=TestDomain,DC=local");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry childEntry = ouEntry.Children.Add("CN=TestUser" + i,  "user");
        childEntry.CommitChanges();
        ouEntry.CommitChanges();
        childEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
        childEntry.CommitChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use @Nick's code (wrapped in `using` statements so the context and principal are disposed properly).  As for privileges, you'll need to at least have enough privileges on the OU where you are creating the user to create and manage objects.   I'd create a specific user under which your program will run and give it just enough privileges to do the tasks that it needs in that specific OU and no more.

Answer (score 0):

The actual attribute for the password is `unicodePwd`, which requires a specific format that is described in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2). But this is how you can do it:

```
newUser.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("\"NewPassword\"");
```

Doing it this way, you can create the user with a password in one step.