# C# Adding Users to Active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to add users to Active Directory and my code so far is

```
using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
    if (dirEntry.SchemaEntry.Name == "container")
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN= " + username, "User"))
        {
            fullname = fname + " " + lname;
            newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = username;
            newUser.Properties["First name"].Value = fname;
            newUser.Properties["Last name"].Value = lname;
            newUser.Properties["Full name"].Value = fullname;
            newUser.Properties["password"].Value = password;
            newUser.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
```

When I run the program I get the error

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

Any suggestions on how I can make this work? And yes I'm new to Active Directory related stuff.

Comment: can you edit this to be readable?

Comment: at which line are you getting the error?

Comment: i'm getting the error at " newUser.CommitChanges();"

Comment: When I manually make the account on the active directory, I only need to enter first name, last name, (full name is done by itself), username, and password

Answer (score 1):

The Active Directory attributes need to be addressed by their **LDAP names** - not what you see in the GUI....

So try this:

```
using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
{
    if (dirEntry.SchemaEntry.Name == "container")
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + username, "User"))
        {
             fullname = fname + " " + lname;
             newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = username;
             newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = fname;  // first name
             newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lname;    // surname = last name
             newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = fullname;  
             newUser.Properties["password"].Value = password;

             newUser.CommitChanges();
         }
    }
}
```

You can find a great Excel spreadsheet showing the names used in the interactive GUI, and what LDAP names they map to, [on Richard Mueller's web site here](http://www.rlmueller.net/UserAttributes.htm) (check out the "Spreadsheet of all Active Directory attributes" and "Spreadsheet of User Properties in Active Directory Users & Computers MMC.")

Or if you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you could also investigate the new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace, which allows you to use nicely shaped objects to handle common tasks.

Your code would look something like this:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, NULL, ldapPath)
{
    // create a user principal object
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, username, password, true);

    // assign some properties to the user principal
    user.GivenName = fname;
    user.Surname = lname;
    user.DisplayName = fullname;

    // save the user to the directory
    user.Save();
}
```

**Note**: the `ldapPath` should be the container's LDAP path - without any prefixes, e.g. something like `CN=Users,DC=YourCompany,DC=com` - no `LDAP://` or other prefixes.

The plus side is: the `UserPrincipal` object class already contains nice, strongly-typed and more intuitive properties to handle many of the basic tasks, like creating a new user and setting some of its properties.

Comment: I tried your first Solution and it gave me the same error, I'm trying your second solution but "UserPrincipal user= ..." is underlined and it says "invalid initializer member declarator"

Comment: On the second solution i'm getting the error "Unknown error (0x80005000)"

Comment: @GK28: what do your `ldapPath` and `username` look like? Is the `username` valid and unique within its container?

Comment: string ldapPath = "LDAP://CN=Users,DC=YasirTek,DC=com"; and for the username it's just "JJill" since it's test account i'm trying to create

Comment: UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx, username, password, true); For username and password on this, I ofcourse used my credentials which are full admit rights. but end up getting the unknown error (0x80005000)

Comment: @GK28: can you try to use just `CN=Users,DC=YasirTek,DC=com` for your `ldapPath` in the second example? Does that work?

Comment: I did, and I think I might've been having issues since I wasn't runing visual studio on administrator, once I switched it and used the code from this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305857/creating-active-directory-user-with-password-in-c-sharp it worked.

Comment: for finding attribute names also see http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-find-attributes-of-objects-in-active-directory/ and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6822.active-directory-attributes-in-the-aduc-gui-tool.aspx